# how can i loop string variables and display all the outer point for each type

Tags: r

Raw data

```
rawdata <- read.table(text = "segment type    x   y
                  kl  a   1   3
                  kl  a   2   1
                  kl  a   3   10
                  kl  a   6   3
                  kl  a   8   2
                  kl  a   4   6
                  kl  a   3   5
                  kl  a   2   4
                  kl  a   7   10
                  mk  d   1   3
                  mk  d   2   1
                  mk  d   3   9
                  mk  d   6   3
                  mk  d   8   2
                  mk  d   4   6
                  mk  d   3   5
                  mk  d   2   4
                  mk  d   7   6
                  mk  d   9   1
                  mk  d   10  10", header = T)
```

I want to looping rawdata$type and it will bind all the outer point for a and d.

the outer point formula:

```
x <- data.frame(rawdata$x,rawdata$y)
plot(x)
chx <- chull(x)
chx <- data.frame(rbind(x = x[chx, ], x[chx[1], ]))
lines(chx)
chx
```

Comment: a `dput()` of the data would be helpful to create a reproducable answer. Please edit this to your question instead of the "Raw data".

Comment: so just replace the "Raw data" with dput()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will create a `chull` by type:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,length(unique(rawdata$type))))
```

this `par` settings are only for plotting purposes (the plots will thus be arranged side-by-side)

```
for (i in unique(rawdata$type)) {
  x <- data.frame(rawdata$x[rawdata$type == i],rawdata$y[rawdata$type == i])
  plot(x, main = i)
  chx <- chull(x)
  chx <- data.frame(rbind(x = x[chx, ], x[chx[1], ]))
  lines(chx)
  print(i)
  print(chx)
}
```

the output looks like this: 
[image]

you can also easily export them by adding a

```
save(chx, file = paste("chull_type_", i, ".RData", sep = ""))
```

within the loop, to `load()` them later, if needed.

Comment: this is absolutely like i want. the par part i didnt understand much and what do u mean by export them like that?

Comment: tq so much for helping loki. im new in here and couldnt understand much how to proper post the question. im glad u understand what i want

Comment: np. perhaps a look at the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) helps with your next post.